# Python- isinstance- use of PLUS(+) sign

Tags: python, isinstance

Can anyone help me in understanding what is the use of plus(+) sign in using isinstance.

```
In [76]: isinstance('qwert', string)
Out[76]: True

In [77]: isinstance('qwert', string + (int,))
Out[77]: True
```

Especially, this part--> string + (int,)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your variable `string_types` is itself a tuple of string types (e.g. `(str, bytes,)`), the `+` operator is concatenating the `string_types` tuple and the `(int,)` tuple together into something like `(str, bytes, int,)`

Comment: @xlax I cannot understand. Can you tell more detail about how it works or give some references? Why out[77] returns True?

Comment: `string` will not work. you would need to import `string_types` from `six` ..and write `string_types` instead of `string`.

Comment: we are checking whether or not the given input i.e 'qwert' is a "string or int" 
( string_types + (int,) = (basestring, int) ). since the input is a string, it will return True.

`In [78]: string_types + (int,)
Out[78]: (basestring, int)`